# Implementing multithreaded application under C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I am implementing a small database like MySQL.. Its a part of a larger project..

Right now i have designed the core database, by which i mean i have implemented a parser and i can now execute some basic sql queries on my database.. it can store, update, delete and retrieve data from files.. As of now its fine.. however i want to implement this on network..

I want more than one user to be able to access my database server and execute queries on it at the same time... I am working under Linux so there is no issue of portability right now..

I know i need to use Sockets which is fine.. I also know that i need to use a concept like Thread Pool where i will be required to create a maximum number of threads initially and then for each client request wake up a thread and assign it to the client..

As for now what i am unable to figure out is how all this is actually going to be bundled together.. Where should i implement multithreading.. on client side / server side.? how is my parser going to be configured to take input from each of the clients separately?(mostly via files i think?)

If anyone has idea about how i can implement this pls do tell me bcos i am stuck here in this project...

Thanks.. :)

Comment: Just curious; why aren't you using [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)?

Comment: Probably a learning db or a homework db he's looking to take further.

Comment: @sixletters: not a homework.. i'm working on a paper.. implementing storage mechanisms for storing data at untrusted service providers..

Comment: @darioo: i'm not using SQLite since i m implementing a basic database myself which is done..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already, take a look at [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html) to get your hands dirty in some socket programming.

Next I would take his [example of a stream client and server](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/clientserver.html) and just use that as a single threaded query system. Once you have got this down, you'll need to choose if you're going to actually use threads or use `select()`. My gut says your on disk database doesn't yet support parallel writes (maybe reads), so likely a single server thread servicing requests is your best bet for starters!

In the multiple client model, you could use a simple per-socket hashtable of client information and return any results immediately when you process their query. Once you get into threading with the networking and db queries, it can get pretty complicated. So work up from the single client, add polling for multiple clients, and then start reading up on and tackling threaded (probably with [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)) client-server models.

Comment: @sixletters: Yes as of now i am primarily concerned about getting the network up and working and den probably after that i may think of adding functionality like multiple clients then multiple access and then in the same context read/write conflicts handling.. Now i am trying a single client code as a starter.. Thanks for the solution, it helped.. :)

Comment: @pratik: you're welcome sir. The `pthread` library contains a read-write lock implementation which may be a simple way to add multiple readers/writers to your server if you add threads.

Answer (score 2):

Server side, as it is the only person who can understand the information. You need to design locks or come up with your own model to make sure that the modification/editing doesn't affect those getting served.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to multithreading, you might consider event-based single threaded approach (e.g. using poll or epoll). An example of a very fast (non-SQL) database which uses exactly this approach is redis.

This design has two obvious disadvantages: you only ever use a single CPU core, and a lengthy query will block other clients for a noticeable time. However, if queries are reasonably fast, nobody will notice.

On the other hand, the single thread design has the advantage of automatically serializing requests. There are no ambiguities, no locking needs. No write can come in between a read (or another write), it just can't happen.
If you don't have something like a robust, working MVCC built into your database (or are at least working on it), knowing that you need not worry can be a huge advantage. Concurrent reads are not so much an issue, but concurrent reads and writes are.

Alternatively, you might consider doing the input/output and syntax checking in one thread, and running the actual queries in another (query passed via a queue). That, too, will remove the synchronisation woes, and it will at least offer *some* latency hiding and some multi-core.

Comment: yes actually for now i am not much bothered about MVCC and i dont have also one in my database code.. for now i think it would be nice as you mentioned running actual queries in one thread and syntax checking in another... 
Also about event based i'm looking into it.. may be it can just serve the purpose..

Comment: Without MVCC, you must use reader-writer locks. Naively implemented (database-level or table-level locking) this will negate most if not all benefits of multithreading unless you have mostly reads with ony very few updates. Row level locking is better, but obviously more hassle, too (and, no panacea either). So, in that case, having everything serialized may indeed save some headaches. Do you, by any chance, already use Boost? If you do, you can look into asio for a no extra cost portable solution (though hand-coding epoll is really easy... only downside is it's not portable).